# CodeIgniter with Bootstrap form issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a form to not use the typical domain.com?q=query and to be able to get a nice domain.com/query instead so I can read the URL within codeIgnitor but I am struggling.

This is my form:

```
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search" method="get" action="<?=$data['link']?>" onsubmit="DoSubmit();">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q" id="q">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by going via a redirect file.